# Angular(+11) Mono Repo different from other versions

Tags: angular, typescript, javascript-framework, monorepo

What is Angular(+11) Mono Repo and how is it different from the other versions of Angular and should you know TypeScript for Angular (+11) mono Repo? I'm trying to find a course to learn more about Angular and I noticed there are not that many on Angular +11. If I learned any version of Angular would I still be learning the important concepts used in the newest version? I want to make sure I'm not learning something outdated from a course I find.

Comment: Any version from Angular 9 upwards would be fine. Just make sure it is absolutely not a version lower then 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm watching now courses from udemy for Angular, the speaker says at the beginning that Angular decided to release a new version each half-year to keep constantly growing and reduce the pain of migrations, therefore these numbers do not matter that much between 2-11. The only essential difference is AngularJS (Angular 1) and Angular (2-11).

https://angular.io/guide/releases#release-frequency

About Angular Monorepos, it's more like a pattern, not a language or technology. A tool for helping with that is Lerna and Nx.dev

I have worked with nx.dev and I can tell you that it's awesome. Watch the intro Video:

https://nx.dev/latest/angular/getting-started/intro

Comment: If you dont mind me asking which Udemy course have you watched? I am considering getting the one by Maximilian Schwarzmüller, do you have any suggestions? @Eugene

Comment: That's exactly the one: https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-guide-to-angular-2/